# bash. Как перевести строку в дату?

Tags: bash

Пытаюсь полученную дату перевести в формат даты.
Дата не верно парсится.
Делаю примерно так:

```
DATE=2022-09-09
s=$(date -d ${DATE} +%s)
ss=$(date -d @$s +%Y_%M_%D)
echo $ss
```

Вывод не корректный:
2022_00_09/09/22

Пробовал и по "науке":

```
s=$(date -d "${DATE}" +"%s")
```

Также пробовал и разный формат ввода строки:
DATE=20220909, DATE=09/09/2022
Результат всегда одинаков.

Comment: Надо не "%Y_%M_%D", а "%Y_%m_%d". Или, ещё быстрее, `echo $DATE |tr - _`

Comment: Спасибо, сработало. И ведь я уже наступал на эти грабли %M_%D и %m_%d. Надо быть внимательнее. Что такое  |tr - _? Как это загуглить или где про это прочесть?

Comment: Про команду [`tr`](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?category=1&topic=tr) тоже можно прочесть в мануалах, наберите `man tr`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Наберите в командной строке `man date`, вы [увидите](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=date&category=1), что:

```bash
    %d    день месяца (например, 01)
    %D    дата; аналогично %m/%d/%y
    %m    месяц (01..12)
    %M    минута (00..59)
```

Как вам уже подсказал @user_587, используйте `%m` и `%d` для вывода даты.

Comment: И вам большое спасибо! Действительно, все написано в справке....

Answer (score 1):

Если вам надо заменить - на _ то проще сделать так:

```
DATE=2022-09-09
$ echo ${DATE//-/_}
2022_09_09
```